# Severe delay when performing "sudo apt-get update" after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: apt, updates

After upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10

"sudo apt-get update"  stalls for a long time when connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com

I do not have this issue on other computers running 16.04 or 16.10

So it is not an internet issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the software download server from `us.archive.ubuntu.com` to `archive.ubuntu.com` :

[image]

Update addressing your comment that you don't have this problem on your other machines :
Check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all entries in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder.
Remove all incorrect entries (in case there are some) and replace them with [the original ones](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23398066/).
Then run `sudo apt update` again, now everything should work fine, just the way as expected.

Comment: I have the same issue with both servers. I do not have the issue in other computers in my house. It seems that it is waiting for something.

Comment: I have the default sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties.  The delay is when accessing archive.ubuntu.com. I have no issues with my network

Comment: @user63726 : Okay, then it looks like something did go completely wrong during the upgrade process - you may want to consider performing a fresh installation ! :)